# Who are the Linux Memory "subsystem" developers?

Tags: linux, memory

After an hour of googling, I still cannot find Linux Memory subsystem developers contact e-mail.

**Question**: Where is the webpage that shows who develops the Linux kernel, specifically the Memory "subsystem" part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux kernel maintainers are listed in the [MAINTAINERS](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/MAINTAINERS) file in the kernel source code. There's a specific [section](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/MAINTAINERS#L6331) for memory management:

```
MEMORY MANAGEMENT
L:      linux-mm@kvack.org
W:      http://www.linux-mm.org
S:      Maintained
F:      include/linux/mm.h
F:      include/linux/gfp.h
F:      include/linux/mmzone.h
F:      include/linux/memory_hotplug.h
F:      include/linux/vmalloc.h
F:      mm/
```